# Create DVDs from squared pixel videos without losing definition

Tags: video, dvd, video-editing

I have to create a couple of DVDs using a bunch of videos that are already created. These videos have all the following specifications:

- Resolution: 1280 x 720
- Format: .mov (I believe using de H.264 codec)
- Video bitrare: around 10 Mbps

When I use any software to create DVDs (for example Adobe Encore) or to just convert the files to NTSC DVD format (for example Premiere), always using the 16:9 DVD output format (720 x 480) I notice the following 2 things:

1. Two small vertical lines show on both sides
2. The definition decreases A LOT (not just the resolution)

Point 1 doesn't concern me too much, it's not a big deal.  Point 2 is actually pretty bad, the output definition of the videos is almost unacceptable, specially when the input videos have very good quality. I believe that this loss of definition might be because the difference in the aspect ratio of the pixels of the input format (square pixels) and output format (non-square pixels).

Is there any way I can keep the definition/quality of the output videos as high as possible? The input videos are what they are, I can't change them...

Capture 1 (input video, picture is a link):

[image: pic]

Capture 2 (output video, picture is a link):

[image: pic]

The encoding of the second video is: mpg-2 NTSC Widescreen, max quality (in Premiere) with target of 8 Mbps.

Comment: What do you mean by "the definition decreases" if not the resolution? Can you describe what you are seeing: blurriness, [blocky textures](http://img119.imageshack.us/img119/2081/blockyjy8.jpg), noise in the image?

Comment: I think that the closest thing would be blocky textures, all the edges seem a little out of place (so not just when there's less resolution that borders are less defined, but also like there's something else going on. It looks like every other line of pixels is a little out of place. There's no blurriness or noise definitely...

Comment: Please post before/after screenshots showing the quality issues you have.

Comment: @CongXu: I've included screen captures of before/after

Comment: Those quality issues looks pretty standard for downscaling. The best you can do is use the best quality you can (try Handbrake with max quality settings). Since your video is basically a desktop screen-grab, in future I would advise capturing at the same or similar resolution as your final output, to avoid any rescaling.